# Complex Analysis: Application of Argument Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across this question the other day and I have been stuck with it for a few days already:

Let f be a holomorphic function defined in a neighbourhood of the disk centred at 0 with radius R, and f has no zeroes on the circle (0, R). Let N be the number of zeroes inside D(0,R). Prove that

$$ max_{|z|=R} (Re(z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)})) \geq N  $$

where Re(*) denotes the real part of a complex function.

I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\Gamma$ is the circle (positively oriented), and the $N$ zeros are counted by multiplicity,

$$\int_0^{2\pi} R e^{i\theta} \dfrac{f'(R e^{i\theta})}{f(R e^{i\theta})} \; d\theta 
=  \dfrac{1}{i} \oint_{\Gamma} \dfrac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz = 2 \pi  N$$
which says that the average value of $\text{Re}(z f'(z)/f(z))$ over the circle is $N$ (and the average value of the imaginary part is $0$).  The maximum value  is greater than or equal to the average value.